# Question about the location of the git repository when deploying Django project on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i'm new in both python and elastic beanstalk. Here's my file structure:

```
/.git # <- here's my git repo
/my-first-django
  |-- django-project
      |-- app
      |-- django-project
      |   |-- __init__.py
      |   |-- settings.py
      |   |-- urls.py
      |   `-- wsgi.py
      `-- manage.py
/venv
```

When I read [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html), I can see they create git repository at the same level as `django-project`. Should I move the repository? Or am I fine with my current structure when deploying with `awsebcli`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are two directories named `django-project` here; did you mean the level of `django-project`, or the level of `django-project`?  In any case this is really a question of which files you want in each commit, such that those files are extracted by a `git clone` or `git checkout`. Git itself doesn't care where you put it except that Git will only store those files that are in the working tree and thus added to / stored in the index/staging-area.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the parent one.

Comment: And does my current structure cause some kind of error when deploying?

Comment: You probably *don't* want to store the venv files. You can either exclude them by never adding them, or by putting the `.git` down one level so that it becomes impossible to add them. But I don't write these projects myself, so that's up to you. I'll leave this for django and EB folks to answer.

Comment: @torek is right - you *don’t* want to store venv files in your repo. Not sure if I can answer your specific questions around EB config/errors, but IMO, you should move the repo to follow EB. Couldn’t hurt :shrug:

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put .gitignore to the question. I actually have .gitignore that ignores venv directory.

Comment: And how can I move .git down one level without damaging the previous commits?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem when you are trying to deploy your Django app
automatic CI/CD pipelines such as Heroku, awsebcli, azure-app service, etc.

The problem is that those services assume that your root directory is where your wsgi.py or asgi.py or you can say your Django project is in your root directory.
Therefore you should change your project structure from this

```
/.git # <- here's my git repo
/my-first-django
  |-- django-project
      |-- app
      |-- django-project
      |   |-- __init__.py
      |   |-- settings.py
      |   |-- urls.py
      |   |-- wsgi.py
      |   |-- manage.py
/venv
```

to

```
 /.git # <- here's my git repo
 |-- django-project
 |-- app
 |-- django-project
    |    |-- __init__.py
    |    |-- settings.py
    |    |-- urls.py
    |    | -- wsgi.py
 |-- manage.py
 /venv
```

Your Django Project should be in the root directory. Also, remember to .gitignore your virtual environment